# Why would Bugzilla exclude assignee when e-mailing bug updates?

Tags: email, bugzilla

Suppose there was a bug opened by member1, assigned to me, cced to member2. I then added a comment in it and changed assignee to member2 at the same time. Bugzilla sent an email to member1, but said it excluded me and member2. I can understand why it would exclude me, but why would it exclude member2? Isn't assignee supposed to know he's now assigned? Is this a bug in Bugzilla?

This is with Bugzilla 4.2.4 (latest stable).

Answer (score 1):

It is worth looking at the excluded team member's email preferences. There are many option for when the assignee gets sent emails or not.

Answer (score 0):

Each user is allowed to set their own individual preferences. In fact, you can change yours so that you get notified even on your own changes.

You shouldn't worry about who gets email from Bugzilla. There may be recipients you didn't expect to get mail, and users you expected to get email aren't recipients.

When I was one of the few administrators of one of the very largest Bugzilla instances, I'd get requests for Bugzilla not to send email to some people and occasionally to force other people to get email. I'd always tell these people "no," because the email preferences of other users aren't theirs to decide.